# Quickblox Flutter SDK Example WebRTC doesn't connect

Tags: flutter, quickblox

I'm having trouble in the Flutter SDK Example project.

Specifically the WebRTC portion. I'm unable to get a video call connected.

I have the project deployed to two Android devices. One is physical, the other is an emulator.

I updated the credentials.dart to match my application information.

One device/app has user1. Other device/app has user2. With the opponents pointed to each other.

The steps I have performed are as follows:

1. Settings -> init
2. Auth -> Login
3. Chat -> Connect
4. WebRTC -> init
5. WebRTC -> Subscribe Events WebRTC
6. WebRTC -> Call WebRTC

I can see debug info in each app, after I click call, so it seems as though the 'chat' connection is working to deliver the messages.

When I try to 'accept' I get an error that 'id' is a required parameter.

Looking at the example source, it seem the 'sessionId' is only ever set when a call is placed. How would the receiving end ever get the sessionId?

Also, anything like 'enable video' or 'start rendering local' results in a null ref error being displayed in a dialog.

Comment: Update:
I pulled into my project, and when I initiate a call, I see it on the “other end”, in the XMPP messages.

Issue now seems as though the `await QB.webrtc.subscribeRTCEventTypes` callback is never fired for CALL or RECEIVED_VIDEO_TRACK.

I call it after the:

settings.init()
auth.login()
chat.connect()
webrtc.init()

All of those inside of Flutter's initState().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm the latest [SDK](https://pub.dev/packages/quickblox_sdk/versions/0.2.4-alpha) (0.2.4-alpha) fixes the issue.

Also, be sure to grant the Camera and Microphone permissions.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

QuickBlox team has resolved this issue in an updated version of [Flutter SDK](https://pub.dev/packages/quickblox_sdk/versions/0.2.4-alpha).

Now the described logic is working correctly.

Comment: I updated to the latest SDK.

I’m able to get the call connected, but no audio or video is coming through. I’m using the example app within the SDK.

The await QB.webrtc.subscribeRTCEventTypes now works for the QBRTCEventTypes.CALL type, and a Dialog opens to ‘Accept’ the call.

However, the await QB.webrtc.subscribeRTCEventTypes for the QBRTCEventTypes.RECEIVED_VIDEO_TRACK type does not trigger.

Do you have any advice? Again, I’m working on one physical Android and one emulator. Both Pixel 2.

Comment: @ToddDeLand were you able to resolve this issue ? i am also not able to resolve this, m able to create a call, can hear audio but video is not coming as u mentioned in the above comment.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64047711/quickblox-flutter-sdk-call-is-happening-but-video-is-not-streaming

Comment: @UdayRamjiyani yes, at the time (Apr. 14) the updated Flutter SDK resolved the issue. I haven't used this project in quite some time now so I'm not certain if it continues to work.